# I want to develop a Rsync script to recursively copy the list of files/folders that are created on one server to another server

Tags: unix, rsync

I want to develop a Rsync script to recursively copy the list of files/folders that are created on one server to another server. I'm using the below command to copy a particular file. However whether we can include a list of files that should be ignored while copying the files from source to destination.

rsync -av --include /sourcepath/* --exclude filename user@destinationserver:/destinationpath

Answer (score 0):

We can refer [1]   [1]: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/rsync.html

rsync -lapv --include /sourcecpath/* --exclude-from exclude-list-one user@destinationserver:/destinationpath

-l, --links copy symlinks as symlinks 
-a, --archive archive mode; same as -rlptgoD (no -H) 
-v, --verbose increase verbosity 
-p, --perms preserve permissions 
--exclude-from=FILE read exclude patterns from FILE